# Need to show view above of seekbar at specific position android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-seekbar

I want to show `seekbar` with dashed line as per below images . This line will be display dynamically based on low/high value. I have attached below image.[image]

I have achieved below image. Can you please help me in this?

[image]

Comment: Please do not close this question if you haven't any reason yet.

Comment: _This line will be display dynamically based on low/high value_ But how the dashed line will be changed? Is it your secondary progress? If you haven't done dashed line that you can make custom shape file and apply as a secondary progress drawable to seekbar.

Comment: @Piyush when the seekbar will initialize then the dotted line will display initialy when i am passing some value like 15,20.

Comment: How are you setting value for it?

Comment: based on before progress

Answer (score 0):

Add your progress bar inside a constraint layout and have its width set to match the parent. Add two imageviews on top of it that have the dotted line as a resource. Add two vertical guidelines and restrict each imageview to the appropriate guideline. Set the percentage of the guidelines to be where you want each time on the progress bar and the views will move accordingly. You can programmatically change the percentage of the guidelines like so:

```
Guideline guideLineLeft = (Guideline) findViewById(R.id.your_left_guideline);
Guideline guideLineRight = (Guideline) findViewById(R.id.your_right_guideline);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideLineLeft.getLayoutParams();
params.guidePercent = 0.10f; // 10% 
guideLineLeft.setLayoutParams(params);
guideLineRight.getLayoutParams();
params.guidePercent = 0.90f; // 90% 
guideLineRight.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**UPDATE after comment**:

[image: example]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_divider_more" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_divider_more" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.21" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.80"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please give me xml demo for this? because i am new for constraint layout

Comment: @dipali added a samplelayout